# Having trouble getting database connected to frontend and am getting an error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

Hi I'm trying to get my firebase database connected to my vue frontend but when I try to do that I get the following error.

Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/firebase_app.js?v=42c663d6' does not provide an export named 'default'

Here is the code its refering to.

```
import { projectFirestore } from "../Firebase/Config";

const getPremium = () => {
    const profiles = ref([])
    const error = ref(null)

    const load = async () => {
        try{
            const res = await projectFirestore.collection('profiles').get()

            profiles.value = res.docs.map(doc => {
               // console.log(doc.data())
               return {...doc.data(), id: doc.id}
            })
        }
        catch (err){
            error.value = err.message
            console.log(error.value)
        }
    }

    return { profiles, error, load}
}

export default getPremium
```

I have seen similar questions regarding this but adding to the vite.config.js doesn't work and to be honest I'm a bit confused as to what the actual problem is as I'm new to this and I think it might be that it can't find where to export getPremium from but could be completely wrong if someone could explain whats going wrong it would be a great help thanks.

Comment: Pretty sure this is a firebase v9 issue or alike. Make a search with this kind of migration issue or check their documentation IMO.

Answer (score 1):

You may import firebase module like ↓

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
```

As you can see, in firebase_app.js uses `export { ... }` (named export), so if you want to use some functions in this module, you need to used **named import**

[image]

Something like `import { xxx } from 'xxx'`

**NOTE**

In firebase v9, you can import module looks like ↓

```
// v9 compat packages are API compatible with v8 code
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
```

Have a look at [official migration docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade)